# DataTemplate only specify binding not the type

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have this bit of code where I have a List of wrapped child classes. I want to specify that the ContentTemplate binds directly to the child class and not the wrapper class. My question is how can I specify the binding, without specifying the type (as this gets resolved by a datatemplate in my app.xaml).

The Code:

```
                    <TabControl Name="tc_TabItems" 
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Value.CheckedItems}" 
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
                        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:CommandsViewModel}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.Name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

                    </TabControl>
```

The App.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type commandBaseModels:MotionCommandViewModel}">
        <commandBase:MotionCommandView/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type commandBaseModels:NonMotionCommandViewModel}">
        <commandBase:NonMotionCommandView/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

For the header of the tab you can see I bind the text to the child class, but I manually set a textblock, Im basically looking to do the same thing but not specify what control to be put there. like so

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate Binding="{Value}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I forgot that `ContentPresenter` was a thing, but it ended up allowing me to get what I was looking for